# XSRF-TOKEN token sent still getting 419 (CSRF token mismatch) using Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel-sanctum

I am building a **Laravel10**+**Vue3** SPA. I initialized my laravel application using **Laravel Breeze** (only API portion) starter kit. I didn't change any default configuration of it in any places (e.g. `config/cors.php`, `config/sanctum.php`, `config/session.php`, etc.). Just I did **two** obvious changes in my `.env` file:

```bash
...
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:5173
...
```

On localhost, everything works fine without any issue. But, when I deploy it to a shared hosting, it's getting issues! To understand the context, I am keeping my **backend** into a subfolder called **laravel-breeze-api** and **frontend** into a subfolder called **frontend**. The changes in the `.env` file are as follows:

```bash
...
APP_URL=http://tiny-url-builder.c1.is/laravel-breeze-api
FRONTEND_URL=http://tiny-url-builder.c1.is/frontend
...
```

When I test the API from postman, it works without any issue.

[image]

But, when I test from the browser, I am constantly getting **419 (proxy reauthentication required)**.

[image]

I am correctly calling `sanctum/csrf-cookie` before calling the `login` endpoint and it correctly saves the necessary cookies.

[image]

On the `/login` api call the **request headers** are also containing those values, but I am getting **CSRF token mismatch** constantly.

[image]

Kindly assist me to understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated the problem in more depth and found a simple solution. If I look into my `config/sanctum.php` file, I do see:

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    )
)),
```

So, I expected the `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` would be filled properly as it is also adding my `FRONTEND_URL` from `.env` file. What I didn't notice is that: `parse_url` method is being used with the second parameter `PHP_URL_HOST`. So, the actual value which was getting set was `tiny-url-builder.c1.is` (without URL scheme).

It wouldn't work in the shared hosting environment I was dealing with. So, the simple solution I found is to add an extra `.env` variable `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` and set its value to either `localhost` or `http://tiny-url-builder.c1.is` (with URL scheme).